# Qt ODBC Microsot SQL Server 2014 issue which happens once a month

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt, odbc

I have developed for windows server 2016, a server application written in C++ with Qt/ODBC/MS Sql Server 2014 which works well. Users log into the application with their login/password. The server application make requests to MS SQL server thanks to ODBC driver.

But about once a month, the login functionnality stops to work and it seems that the application cannot access to the database anymore.

The login process uses this peace of code :

```
SQLServerConnexion::SQLServerConnexion(const std::string &dbname)
{
 dbname_ = QString(dbname.c_str());
 database_ = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC", generatedUUID().c_str());
 database_.setDatabaseName(dbname_);

 if (database_.open()) {
    qDebug() << dbname_ << "opened";
 }
 else {
    qDebug() << "Cannot open " << dbname_;
 }
}
```

dbname follows the following pattern "DB_NAME; MARS_Connection=YES;"

When I restart the application, users can log into the application.
I don't understand why this issue happens about once a month. Have you got some ideas to solve that issue ?

Comment: Check the log files of your application and database for some hints? If there are no loggings from your app, add them and observe the behavior. There might be gazillion reasons for a behavior like that

Comment: And what error message is generated when this fails? Just guessing but it appears that your code "eats" the error and displays a rather unuseful error message. If so, you need to change that for anyone to assist.

Comment: I put a log file, and it appears today the message : "[odbc driver manager] data source name not found and no default driver specified". I emphasize on the fact that the server application worked until today.